# R power.prop.test and power equation in the difference between proportions

Tags: r, proportion, statistical-power

I am looking into the formula built into the ***R*** function `power.prop.test{stats}` and I am stuck trying to understand the following calculation:

```
p.body <- quote(pnorm(((sqrt(n) * abs(p1 - p2) - (qnorm(sig.level/tside, 
lower.tail = FALSE) 
* sqrt((p1 + p2) * (1 - (p1 + p2)/2))))
/sqrt(p1 *(1 - p1) + p2 * (1 - p2)))))
```

Shouldn't `sqrt((p1 + p2) * (1 - (p1 + p2)/2))` ($\sqrt{(p_1 + p_2) (1 - \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}))}$) really be `sqrt((p1 + p2)/2 * (1 - (p1 + p2)/2))` ($\sqrt{\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2} (1 - \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2})}$) since we seem to be trying to be working with the average of proportions and multiplying complements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the denominator only contained the standard error of the difference in proportions, calculated under the null, then you'd be right that there's a missing $2$.

However, the denominator contains another term.

We have that $\text{var}_0(p_1-p_2) = p(1-p) (\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2})$

In the function, $n_1=n_2=n$, so

$\text{sd}_0(p_1-p_2) = \sqrt{p(1-p)}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$

The numerator in the formula you show contains the term $\sqrt{n}$ but the $\sqrt 2$ there is taken inside the estimate of $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ to cancel out the $2$ you worry is missing.